# Logging in with Facebook on Firebase with Test Users iOS

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-authentication

I need to use the Firebase backend with Facebook login. However, attempting to login with test users from Facebook, reveals this error:

[image]

However, upon setting my app to public, then this error appears:

[image]

How can I test Firebase with Facebook login, if the test users are not permitted?

Answer (score 0):

Solved my question. I was using users from another Facebook test app I had setup. I simply created users and it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

here share one pic in that pic there is on off switch with green color top right corner[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgmwy.png) make sure it on. because I have faced same problem while try to rub app in physical device

Comment: paste image if possible and then write your description explaining your answer.